# SQLite error with simple query

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I'm attempting to modify a very old project by another developer, to get it to compile without error in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, and with the newest versions of its dependencies.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to determine exactly which SQLite wrapper was used in this project, but based on the names of certain functions used -- such as `FieldAsInteger` -- I believe it to be [this one](https://www.itwriting.com/blog/articles/a-simple-delphi-wrapper-for-sqlite-3)

The project compiles just fun, however, shortly after launch this error is thrown:

`Error executing SQL.
Error 1: SQL error or missing database.
"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table""`
[image: SQL error message]

As best as I can tell, the database is found and loaded successfully, and if I run the query `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = "table"` in an SQLite management app, the query runs successfully and returns the expected results.

What could possibly be going wrong? I've stepped through the code in question and haven't seen anything strange. I'm also curious about the inclusion of random Chinese characters in the error message.

Comment: seems like you have not selected a database before you try to execute the query

Comment: @messerbill Do you mean loading the initial database? I have `TheDB := TSQLiteDatabase.Create(DBNameandPath);` that seems to run without issue. Looking at the official sample for this wrapper, it doesn't appear anything beyond that is needed.

Comment: Sounds like the project along with the library were written for ANSI version of Delphi.

Comment: @Victoria Then, would this be an incompatibility with this version of Delphi? Something that can only be done in an old version?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was using the ANSI version of that library rather than the Unicode version which is available on the same page. Thanks for the hint @Victoria!